# Satisfied and modeled concept?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, c++-concepts

### Introduction

The standard specifies that each concept is related to two predicates:

1. predicate "is statisfied by": a concept is satisfied by a sequence of template argument when it evaluates to true. This is almost a syntactic check.
2. predicate "is modeled by": *A sequence Args of template arguments is said to model a concept C if Args satisfies C ([temp.constr.decl]) and meets all semantic requirements (if any) given in the specification of C.*  [[res.on.requirements]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/res.on.requirements)

For some concepts, the requirements that makes a satisfied concept modeled are clearly expressed. Example [[concept.assignable]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/concept.assignable)

> LHS and RHS model assignable_­from<LHS, RHS> only if

> - addressof(lhs = rhs) == addressof(lcopy)

> - [...]

But I wonder if the syntactic requirements also implicitly implies semantic requirements.

### Question

**Does the syntactic predicates implicitly imply requirement for the concept to be modeled ?**

I see two kind of implicit requirement:

1. The concept is satisfied because syntactically checked expressions are unevaluated expressions and such expressions would result in the program being ill-formed if those expressions were not unevaluated expressions.
2. The concept is satisfied because syntactically checked expressions are not evaluated but evaluation of those expression would result in the program having undefined behavior.

### Examples

For example, let's consider the `default_initializable` concept, defined here: [[concept.default.init]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/concept.default.init).

`default_initializable` is satisfied by `A<int>` but the program is ill-formed if a variable of type `A<int>` is default-initialized ([demo](https://godbolt.org/z/p-_JsY)):

```
template <class T>
struct A { 
    A() {
       f(T{});
       }
    };

static_assert (default_initializable <A<int>>);  // A<int> satisfies default_initializable

A<int> a{}; //compile time error: f not declared in this scope
```

`default_initializable` is satisfied by `A` but default-initialization of `A` result in undefined behavior (when the default-initialization is not preceded by a zero-initialization) (demo):

```
struct A { 
    int c;
    A() {
       c++;
       }
    };

static_assert (default_initializable <A>); // A satisfies default_initializable

auto p = new A;  //undefined behavior: indeterminate-value as operand of operator ++
```

Comment: `default_initializable` doesn't have semantic requirements, so probably not a good example? Like, I guess, "none of these operations exhibit undefined behavior" but that's pretty tedious if you have to repeat it literally everywhere?

Comment: @Barry This is precisely my question. `default_initializable` has no explicit semantic requirements. But does it require that default initialization is well formed and does not cause undefined behavior? Or is `default_initializable` a purely syntactic concept?

Comment: @Oliv: "*`default_initializable` has no explicit semantic requirements. But does it require that default initialization is well formed and does not cause undefined behavior?*" Your first sentence answers the second.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> a concept is satisfied by a sequence of template argument when it evaluates to true. This is almost a syntactic check.

No, it is not "almost" anything: it *is* a syntactic check. The constraints specified by a `requires` clause (for example) verify that a specific syntax is legal syntax for that type. This is *all* that "satisfying a concept" means.

> Does the syntactic predicates implicitly imply requirement for the concept to be modeled?

... no. If satisfying a concept also implied modeling the concept, then the standard wouldn't need different terms for these.

The point of having such a distinction is the recognition that the concept language feature can't specify every requirement that concepts as a concept should encapsulate. So satisfying-a-concept is just the language part, while modelling-a-concept includes things that the language can't do.

But that question is kind of separate from what your two examples show. Your examples represent the difference between "valid syntax" and "can be compiled/executed". Satisfying a concept only cares about the former. And modelling a concept only cares about the latter *to the extent* that said semantic behavior is *explicitly* specified.

There is nothing in the standard about implicit semantic requirements. There is no statement to the effect of "all expressions/statements in a concept must be able to be compiled and/or executed in order for it to be modeled". Nor is it intended to.

However much we try to pretend it's more than this, concepts as it exists in C++20 is *nothing more* than a more convenient mechanism for performing SFINAE. SFINAE can't test compilable/executable validity of the contents of some expression, so neither can concepts. And neither does concepts attempt to pretend that it can.

Comment: What a disappointment... I was hoping that concept even without axioms could be viewed as a way to introduce "stronger" types as the one used in type theories. I would prefer that to contract!